# Suppose that A and B are nxn matrices with A row equivalent to B. Prove that if A is nonsingular, then B is row equivalent to In.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that A and B are nxn matrices with A row equivalent to B. Prove that if A is nonsingular, then B is row equivalent to In.

I answered this on a test and it seemed right to me, but got zero  credit. What did I do wrong? Was my logic incorrect?

my answer:

By definition, row equivalence means one matrix can be reduced to another. By definition, an invertible matrix can be row reduced to I, and is row equivalent to I. Since A is invertible, and thus row equivalent to I, B is row equivalent to I, since B is row equivalent to A.

Comment: Seems ok to me :/

Comment: Your logic seems right to me.  (It's probably a theorem in your book, rather than a definition, that an invertible matrix can be row-reduced to I, but that's a minor point.)